# Is there a GNU Octave equivalent for the MATLAB function "getpixelposition"?

Tags: matlab, octave

MATLAB got the function [getpixelposition()](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/getpixelposition.html). Is there an equivalent function or trick for GNU Octave?

Comment: Usually in Octave, if you try to call a function that has not been implemented it will print a message telling you that. What happens if you try to call `getpixelposition`?

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I get `warning: the 'getpixelposition' function is not yet implemented in Octave Please read <https://www.octave.org/missing.html> to learn how you can contribute missing functionality.` Unfortunately, it is not in the alphabetic list or in the bug tracker. I will try to file a bug report.

Comment: I filed a bug report, see https://savannah.gnu.org/bugs/?58181

Comment: The warning message implies that the Octave developers are aware that `getpixelposition` exists in MATLAB. Therefore, I don't think this is a bug, it just hasn't been implemented yet. MATLAB is commercial software that generates a huge amount of money to fund development. Octave is free, so relies on contributions from unpaid volunteers to implement functions. Naturally, this means some aspects of Octave will lag (very) far behind MATLAB.